# Jquery ajax and asp.net mvc 5 data binding

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I am calling using ajax for an MVC method and the data sent in Json format is not being received on the server.
the json format is as follows : {"action":"create","orgId":"1","appId":"1","fillForHimself":"true"}
while the mvc method is
public ActionResult Create(string action,string orgId, string appId,string fillForHimself)

only the parameter action is getting any values while the others are getting nulls

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

since you haven't posted your code, i am only guessing by looking at the example you provided. Try changing the declaration type of orgId and appId to integer and fillForHimeself to boolean. Also you should paste code that helps us answer your question more specifically.